# How to use the code returned from Cognito to get AWS credentials?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

Right now, I'm struggling to understand AWS Cognito so maybe someone could help me out. I set a domain to serve Cognito's hosted UI for my User Pool like what's described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-ux.html). So when I go to `https://<my-domain>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=<MY_POOL_CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8080` I get a login page where my users can login to my app with Google. That part is working great.

I'm confused about what to do with the code that is returned from that page once my user logs in. So once I get redirected to Google and authorize the application to view my information, I get redirected back to one of my URLs with a code in the query params. Right now I'm redirecting to localhost, so the redirect URL look like this:

`https://localhost:8080/?code=XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX`

What exactly is this code? Also, how do I use it to get access to AWS resources for my user?

Comment: You're using the Authorization Code flow.  In this flow, the Hosted UI (running in the user's browser) will authenticate the user against the Cognito User Pool, and return the authorization code.  You must then send this code to your webserver.  Your webserver exchange this code for access tokens, which it uses to finally retrieve the user's information.  As you can see, the user's information, as well as the access tokens, never reach the user's browser; this is the security promise of this entire scheme.  How do your server exchange the code for the token?  See answer by Marcio Ghiraldelli.

Comment: This might be helpful : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFSU6rhFETk&ab_channel=BeABetterDev

Comment: AWS changed their UI a couple times since some of the answers here were posted (and video tutorials they link to). In case you understand the security implications and decide you can do without an Authorization Code (i.e., receive the JWT directly), you can obtain it by using this configuration: In the console, creating a new User Pool, in Step 5 (Integrate your app), check "Use the Cognito Hosted UI", scroll down, expand "Advanced app client settings", and under "OAuth 2.0 grant types", add "Implicit grant". Redirect URL will be something like: `https://localhost:3000/#id_token={id_token}`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

*First off, screw authentication a thousand times. No one deserves to spend half a day looking at this shit.*

Authentication for API Gateway Authorized with Cognito

**Ingredients**

1. `client_id` and `client_secret`: In Cognito > General Settings > App clients you can find the App client id, then click on Show Details to find the App client secret
2. For the header `Authorization: Basic YWJjZGVmZzpvMWZjb28zc...` you need to encode those two with: `Base64Encode(client_id:client_secret)`, for example in Python:

   ```
   import base64  
   base64.b64encode('qcbstohg3o:alksjdlkjdasdksd'.encode()).decode()
   ```

   *side note: Postman also has an option to generate this in Authorization > **Basic Auth***
3. `redirect_uri`: passed in the body, it is the callback url that you configured in App integration > App client settings.
   This MUST match with what you configured or you will get a totally
   unhelpful message `{ "error": "invalid_grant" }`

**Example of a request to get a token from the code:**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://mycognitodomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'code=<use the code you received post login>' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=https://myapp.com'
```

This will return your tokens:

```
{
  "access_token":"eyJz9sdfsdfsdfsd", 
  "refresh_token":"dn43ud8uj32nk2je",
  "id_token":"dmcxd329ujdmkemkd349r",
  "token_type":"Bearer", 
  "expires_in":3600
}
```

Then take the `id_token` and plug into your API call:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://myapigateway.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/' \
--header 'Authorization: <id_token>'
```

**Ok, this is tagged as JavaScript but since we also suffer in Python**

*Friendly reminder: this is an example, please don't hardcode your secrets.*

```py
import requests

# In: General Settings > App clients > Show details
client_id = "ksjahdskaLAJS ..."
client_secret = "dssaKJHSAKJHDSsjdhksjHSKJDskdjhsa..."

# URL in your application that receives the code post-authentication
# (Cognito lets you use localhost for testing purposes)
callback_uri = "http://localhost:8001/accounts/amazon-cognito/login/callback/"

# Find this in: App Integration > Domain
cognito_app_url = "https://my-application-name.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com"

# this is the response code you received - you can get a code to test by going to
# going to App Integration > App client settings > Lunch Hosted UI
# and doing the login steps, even if it redirects you to an invalid URL after login
# you can see the code in the querystring, for example:
# http://localhost:8001/accounts/amazon-cognito/login/callback/?code=b2ca649e-b34a-44a7-be1a-121882e27fe6
code="b2ca649e-b34a-44a7-be1a-121882e27fe6"

token_url = f"{cognito_app_url}/oauth2/token"
auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)

params = {
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "client_id": client_id,
    "code": code,
    "redirect_uri": callback_uri
}

response = requests.post(token_url, auth=auth, data=params)

print(response.json()) # don't judge me, this is an example
```

Comment: Super clear explanation. The confusing part in the original manual is how to build the Authorization in step #2.

Comment: Really clean clear answer. I'm a little confused on where the `<use the code you received post login>` comes from? I'm guessing this comes from the first redirect to the "server" side that would then use the following. (ie https://<your_domain>.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri_server>)

Comment: Yes, after you go through the login page, it will redirect to the `redirect_uri` with a code parameter, something like: 
`http://<your_application_url>/?code=<THIS_CODE>&state=AbcDefgh`

Comment: Getting an `{"error":"invalid_request"}` message - any way to figure out what is going on?

Comment: @Daniel I HATE how bad the return codes are with Cognito, it's really hard to find what's wrong! Most commonly it's routes that are not matching, check in your App Client settings if the callback routes match exactly with routes that are available in your application and check if your application is pointing to the right Cognito route.

Comment: double checked it and i was missing the key `redirect_uri` - but now im slapped with `{"error":"invalid_grant"}` - should the redirect uri be the full url in the Callback URL(s) section of the app client?

Comment: Actually - it looked like the "code" expired - I logged in again, got a new code, and got back a response - thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @bubbassauro - is there any way to convert this to a python request?

Comment: One more gotcha: if you configure multiple callback uris in your app client settings, then it seems that the one you use as the redirect_uri in the /oauth2/token request must match the one that you originally used to obtain the authorization code.

Comment: I was stuck at `{"error":"invalid_request"}`. I then figured out that the request body should not be JSON, rather it is query param -_-

Comment: After fighting for half a century with `invalid_grant` nonsense finally got it working, thanks! What else i can use these tokens for? Can I call AWS services, like start and EC2 using the aws cli?

Comment: Found info here for the validation and the usage of the tokens https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html

Answer (score 14):

To fetch AWS credentials (id_token, access_token and refresh_token) from the code request parameter returned by the authorisation code oath2 flow, you should use your Cognito User Pool web domain `/oauth2/token` endpoint, following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html instructions.

Pay attention to the HTTP Basic Authorisation user and password instructions, it should be your Cognito App `client_id` and `client_secret`, otherwise, you get a `invalid_client` error.

The code flow is supposed to be used server side, as you avoid tokens floating around on URLs. If you're planning to do that client side, you should use the `response_type=token`, as it gives this result directly on the login redirect.

Comment: How do you set the `response_type` to `token` for the redirect URL in the Cognito User Pool?

Comment: The `response_type` shouldn't be set in the redirect URL, but in the initial URL request. See my cognito example application https://github.com/marciogh/my-react-dropbox/blob/master/react/src/App.js#L55

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this is going to be useful 10 months from since it was asked but might be helpful to others.

I have used `response_type=token` (Oauth flow=`implicit grant` & scope=`openid`) & provider as `Cognito`. After you login using the default login page, you will get an `id_token` & `access_token`. You can get a temporary identity for your user using this `id_token`. You also need to have an Federated identity pool setup for this, with roles assigned for  authenticated & unauthenticated users, and linked to the user pool you are authenticating with. Once you have that (assuming you are using javascript), you can follow example at [Cognito user identity pools javascript examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html#using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples-user-pool-identity-pool). My sample code derived from the same -

```
function getAccessToken(idToken, identityPoolId, userPool) {
        let provider = "cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/" + userPool;
        let login = {};

        login[provider] = idToken;

        // Add the User's Id Token to the Cognito credentials login map.
        let credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: identityPoolId,
            Logins: login
        });

        //call refresh method in order to authenticate user and get new temp credentials
        credentials.get((error) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);

                let response = {
                    statusCode: 500,
                    body: JSON.stringify(error)
                };

                return response;

            } else {
                console.log('Successfully logged!');
                console.log('AKI:'+ credentials.accessKeyId);
                console.log('AKS:'+ credentials.secretAccessKey);
                console.log('token:' + credentials.sessionToken);

                let response = {
                    statusCode: 200,
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        'AKI': credentials.accessKeyId,
                        'AKS': credentials.secretAccessKey,
                        'token': credentials.sessionToken
                    })
                };

                return response;
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue, and I wanted to ask what do you mean by "default login". Is it the domain provided by AWS? Because it seems you can only use that website if you select "Authorization code grant" as your OAuth flow (which means, if I'm understanding this correctly, you will get a code and not a token).

Comment: Yes, the login URL you get (or create based on format) when you configure a domain on Cognito. It works with `implicit grant` as well. This is one which works for me - `https://exampledomain.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=token&client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost/portal.html`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more simple/clear way of doing this with Axios:

```
axios.post(`https://${yourCognitoPull}.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token`, null, {
    params: {
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        client_id: 'xxxxx replace with your client id xxxxxx',
        client_secret: 'xxxxx replace with your secret xxxxxx',
        code: 'xxxx code you received from cognito xxxx',
        redirect_uri: 'xxxx replace with the uri that you configure as valid xxxx'
    }
}).then(response => {
        const newAccessToken = response.data.access_token;
}).catch(error => {
        console.log('Error al renovar el token de acceso', error);
});
```

**Very important:** Add the ClientSecret AND the RedirectURI (even if your are not redirecting, just getting the token, because it seems that Cognito checks if you know the valid URI as an additional security check)

*(I strongly recommend doing this in a backend environment to protect the ClientSecret... or encrypting the value someway at least)*

Answer (score 3):

When this is true

```
#1: https://<my-domain>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=<MY_POOL_CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8080
```

The AWS Cognito Redirect will be

```
https://localhost:8080?code=8023253d-1c76-4c70-be3d-c8c29cc18c95
```

Then from your web client, use the returned code in the following app request.

> NOTE: Post Header Content-Type MUST BE 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'; Code is a one time use; redirect_uri from #1 and #2 requests must match.

```
#2: POST https://<my-domain>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=8023253d-1c76-4c70-be3d-c8c29cc18c95&client_id=<MY_POOL_CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8080
```

And will then get a response payload as follows

```
{
  "id_token": "...",
  "access_token": "...",
  "refresh_token": "...",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

NOTE: If you instead have a Custom Domain setup, then the two above calls would change to

```
#1: https://my.custom.auth.domain.com/login?...

#2: https://my.custom.auth.domain.com/oauth2/token?...
```

**UPDATE**

> In regards to comment to extend answer.

I use this library: https://github.com/awslabs/cognito-at-edge on a cloudfront edge.

I actually opened the lib use it locally in a file so that I could change the names of each cookie.

Create a Lambda and add the library to the index.js like this.
There may be a few more steps as I have a utilities folder with csrf.js and cookie.js libs locally. I don't recall why I had to do that. Probably something with using the main lib locally instead of npm installing it.

[image]

Then in your cloudfront add this lambda as the "Viewer Request" with the ARN from the above lambda like this.

[image]

This should solve all your cookie issues as I think the lib attempts a refresh when needed. It's been awhile since I worked on this so memory is a bit lost.

Then for your api gateway, I think there is a setting on any route your add verification, where you say to accept a boolean so that you can return false from your verification lamba.

So make another lambda for API Gateway and attach it. In it just add the following code.

> Verify cookie token on API Gateway route.

```
import { CognitoJwtVerifier } from 'aws-jwt-verify';

import { parseCookies } from './utilities/parse-cookie.mjs';

const verifier = CognitoJwtVerifier.create({
  userPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_POOL_ID,
  tokenUse: "access",
  clientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID
});

const TOKEN_NAME = process.env.COGNITO_TOKEN_NAME;

export const handler = async (event) =>
{
  if (event.cookies === null)
  {
    return {
      isAuthorized: false,
    };
  }

  const TOKEN = parseCookies(event.cookies, TOKEN_NAME);

  if (TOKEN === null)
  {
    return {
      isAuthorized: false,
    };
  }

  try
  {
    await verifier.verify(TOKEN);
  
    return {
      isAuthorized: true,
    };
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    return {
      isAuthorized: false,
    };
  }
};
```

> This will still take you a bit of time as there are many things going on and I could not include it all, but this is the bulk. Working with Edge is cumbersome as the changes don't propagate quickly. I found using the lambda_@_edge lib to be very easy to use and exactly what I was looking for.

Have patience and keep trying a little of the flow at a time until it works, then move on to the API gateway lambda.

You can get the cognito and cloudfront working just using postman requests.

Comment: After you've received the "response payload", what do you do with it? How exactly do you make use of it to maintain the user signed in? Again the 3600 (which I presume to be 1 hour), does it get reset (so as to prolong the session) as long as the user is "signed in".. Would be really helpful to extend this concise and lucid answer of your some ways further!

Answer (score 2):

you can find the "Authorization code grant" in the doc :http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-idp-settings.html

Comment: Hmm, I did read that and see how to use that endpoint described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html. I guess I assumed there was something built into the SDKs that would handle this for me. So what I'm hearing basically is that I should stick to using the `response_type=code` query param for my login page. Using that places the tokens in the URL once the user gets directed. It appears it's either that or I have to make the request for the tokens myself. Does this seem right to you?

Comment: What I meant to say was "I should stick to using the `response_type=token`"

Comment: I'm still confused with the docs. Can I exchange that code with a token somehow? It seems to me the terminology is switching up in the docs. What method in the SDK do I call with the "code" to get user info?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing @bubbassauro. Below my PHP version :

```php
try {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_ENV['URL_COGNITO'].'/oauth2/token');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $headers = [];
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($_ENV['CLIENTID'].':'.$_ENV['CLIENTSECRET']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  http_build_query([
        'grant_type' => "authorization_code",
        'client_id' => $_ENV['CLIENTID'],
        'code' => $code,
        'redirect_uri' => $_ENV['URL_AUTH0']
    ]));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $result= json_decode($result);
    return $result->id_token;

} catch (Exception $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply, You can request the id/access/refresh tokens using the code and the Cognito clientId+hostname, then use the id and access token to identify the user in your API calls.

Comment: "How to use the code returned from Cognito..." is what the user asked. Where is your example?