# AWS cognito - How do I get the token from the code I receive after logging in from Cognito log in form?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

My issue is very similar to the question asked there [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785898/how-to-use-the-code-returned-from-cognito-to-get-aws-credentials](https://stackoverflow.com)

Basically I'm using the Cognito app to login. After successful login, I'm redirected to my application with a code in the query string. I understand that I'm supposed to exchange that code for a token using the following endpoint: /oauth2/token
but I systematically get "400 - bad request" with invalid_client, even though I'm using the same client_id as for /login or /signup.

(I am coding my aws stacks in Typescript)

I'm trying to figure out where the error could come from.

My request looks like this:

`POST https://<domain name>.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?client_id=<client_id>&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200&code=<code I get in the query param after login>`

In the headers:

`Authorization: Basic <app credential>`

`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

And for the `app credential`, I got it from:

`const secret = this.userPoolClient.userPoolClientSecret as any;`

`this.appCredentials = btoa(this.userPoolClient.userPoolClientId + ":" + secret.value);`

...and the body is null

(I understood that I'm supposed to create a SecretManagerStack to store the secret, but right now, I'm just trying to get that token. I'll worry about protecting the secret later)

I have 3 questions:

1. Am I indeed supposed to use /oauth2/token after coming back from Cognito login form or am I supposed to do something different?
2. Am I using that API /oauth2/token correctly with all the necessary inputs and headers?
3. Could I be wrong about the app credentials? How am I supposed to retrieve the client secret?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you are indeed supposed to use the /oauth2/token endpoint to exchange the authorization code for an access token after coming back from the Cognito login form.
2. Your request looks correct to me, assuming that the client_id and code parameters are values that you obtained from Cognito. You can verify this from Cognito console by navigating to the App clients section.
3. The app credentials are generated by combining the client ID and client secret. Looks like you are retrieving the client secret correctly from the userPoolClient.userPoolClientSecret property.

Here are a few things you can check:

- The authorization code is valid. The authorization code has a short
  expiration time, so you need to exchange it for an access token as
  soon as possible after receiving it. The redirect URI is correct. The
  redirect URI must be a registered redirect URI for your app client.
  The Authorization header must be set to Basic . The Content-Type header must be set
  to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. The client ID and client secret
  are properly encoded in the Authorization header. You can use a tool
  like Base64 Encoder/Decoder to verify the encoding. Make sure that
  the request body is empty. The request body should only be used for
  the client_credentials grant type. The grant_type parameter is set
  to authorization_code.